# Custom CSS Won't Override Bootstrap on Wordpress Theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I cannot get my custom CSS to override bootstrap on this site.

I've programmed using bootstrap on many platforms and have never had any problems, but I'm working on a WordPress site for a client and nothing I do is working. I can't assign background colors or similar customizations into classes and stick them in divs, because they just refuse to show up. I can't even use pre-existing bootstrap classes and put them into divs. It's like my CSS file doesn't exist. Basic example:

```
.my-blue-background { 
    background-color: blue;
}

<div class = "container my-blue-background">
    ...
</div>
```

Or even:

```
<div class = "my-blue-background">
    <div class = "container">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Or Even:

```
<div class = "container text-center">
   <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</div>
```

Or even:

```
<div class = "container">
    <h1 class = "text-center">Hello World!</h1>
</div>
```

I've tried using !important. I've tried just copying CSS files and pages from other themes just to see if they would work, and they do, but if I try to change absolutely anything on *their* custom style sheet, it doesn't show up. I've tried just deleting their custom stylesheets entirely and it won't even show up on my website that something different has happened. I have tried clearing my cache, and I've tried viewing the website on different browsers and different computers. My enqueues are set up correctly, to the best of my knowledge, as I've tried both:

```
wp_register_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/css /bootstrap.min.css', false, '4.0.0', null);
wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap');

wp_register_style('customstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/css/custom.css', false, '0.0.1', null);
wp_enqueue_style('customstyle');
```

And:

```
wp_register_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/css /bootstrap.min.css', false, '4.0.0', null);
wp_register_style('customstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/css/custom.css', false, '0.0.1', null);
```

Is there something wrong with my configured settings?

Comment: have you tried to clear cache, because WP caching a lot  ?

Comment: @Mooga First of all, WordPress is the proper spelling, not Wordpress. Second, do not change the Anglicization spellings of words (customization -> customisation, and vice versa). Please reserve suggested edits for edits that objectively improve posts; people have to spend time reviewing edits you attempt below 2,000 reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the cache on the WordPress server side, which wouldn't load my new edits in a reasonable amount of time, making it appear like I couldn't override bootstraps presets. Though I'm not sure it's the proper fix, it was resolved by changing the CSS and Javascript enqueues to:

`wp_enqueue_style('customstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/css/mystyle.css', array(), rand(111,9999), 'all' );
wp_enqueue_script('customjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/js/myscripts.js', array(), rand(111,9999), true);`

It forced the server to reload my new stylesheets and scripts, giving me immediate changes.

Answer (score 0):

I see some  wrong spaces in your html outputs

```
<div class = **the space here is wrong** "container text-center">
```

The correct one is:

```
<div class="container text-center">
```

Comment: I just have bad eyesight and put spacing in my coding drafts for readability's sake so I don't have to increase the text size, since it doesn't affect the code. I highly doubt that's the cause of my issue

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure that the custom style is loaded after the bootstrap style you should do this:

```
wp_register_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/css /bootstrap.min.css', false, '4.0.0', null);
wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap');

wp_register_style('customstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/css/custom.css', array('bootstrap'), '0.0.1', null);
wp_enqueue_style('customstyle');
```

If that doesn't solve it, a link to the website would help a lot.